# Is there a way to check if OSX .pkg is signed on LInux(Ubuntu)

Tags: 20.04, macosx

There is a command `pkgutil --check-signature "path/to/pkg"` for macOS to check the signature of a package. Is there a way somehow to check if the osx .pkg is signed or not on Linux(Ubuntu)? Is it even logically possible?

Comment: You can do it with `dpkg-sig`:  https://hussainaliakbar.github.io/digitally-signing-and-verification-of-debian-packages-with-dpkg-sig/

Comment: It looks like checking the linux packages, but I'm asking about osx .pkg check on linux